# Why do I have to use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` in order to set a filter criterion?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In order to apply a filter criterion on a form, I have to execute

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strFilter
```

I find this rather unintuitive. In fact, I have expected and searched for something like

```
call frmFoo.setFilter(strFilter)
```

or similar. Besides, to "enable" the filter, I have to use the more intuitive `frmFoo.filterOn = true`/`me.filterOn=true`. Is there a reason for that or is it just because the developers of access thought that to be right?

It is also unclear to me how access "knows" what form the filter needs to be applied on when `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` is called. Obviously, there seems to be something like a *current form* that is unknown to me.

Comment: DoCmd.ApplyFilter works on the currently active form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
```